# Swift. CoreGraphics, addRects and fillPath fill only 1 rect

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

So, I'm following a tutorial that's in Objective-C and I'm doing the same things using Swift.

My code fills only 1 rectangle and I expect it to fill 3.

```
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
let rects = [CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100),
             CGRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100),
             CGRect(x: 500, y: 500, width: 100, height: 100)]

context?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
context?.addRects(rects)
context?.fillPath()
```

Tutorial code(objc) that works:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor red].CGColor);
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(200, 200, 100, 100);
CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectMake(300, 300, 100, 100);
CGContextFillPath(context)
```

Is there something I'm missing? And also, I can call  `context?.addRects(rects)` or `context!.addRects(rects)` and they both work, which one should I use?

P.S.
Here's my `print(context?.path)`

```
  moveto (100, 100)
    lineto (200, 100)
    lineto (200, 200)
    lineto (100, 200)
    closepath
  moveto (300, 300)
    lineto (400, 300)
    lineto (400, 400)
    lineto (300, 400)
    closepath
  moveto (500, 500)
    lineto (600, 500)
    lineto (600, 600)
    lineto (500, 600)
    closepath
```

Comment: Worked fine for me... are you sure your view is greater than `300 x 300`?

Comment: @DonMag It wasn't greater.. now it works, thank you